# Lightweight blog engine for existing aspnet core MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blogs, blog-engine

I'm building a site using dot net core 2.1 MVC.

I want to find a lightweight blog engine that I can install via something like nuget (instead of rolling my own crappy version!)

[MiniBlog.Core](https://github.com/madskristensen/Miniblog.Core)

Looks great but it's a Template and doesn't let me install via nuget to an existing project - maybe there is another way to do this?

I hear static site generators are gaining popularity e.g. [Wyam](https://wyam.io/recipes/blog/overview) but again I'm unsure how to integrate one of these.

Any suggestions appreciated!